# ContentType Issue -- Human is an idiot - Can't figure out how to tie the original model to a ContentType abstracted 'Favorite' model

Tags: django, models, contenttype

Originally started here: [Django IN query as a string result - invalid literal for int() with base 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650181/django-in-query-as-a-string-result-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

I have a number of apps within my site, currently working with a simple "Blog" app.  I have developed a 'Favorite' app, easily enough, that leverages the ContentType framework in Django to allow me to have a 'favorite' of any type... trying to go the other way, however, I don't know what I'm doing, and can't find any examples for.

I'll start off with the favorite model:

### favorite/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Favorite(models.Model):
        content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
        object_id       = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        user            = models.ForeignKey(User)
        content_object  = generic.GenericForeignKey()

        class Admin:
                list_display = ('key', 'id', 'user')

        class Meta:
                unique_together = ("content_type", "object_id", "user")
```

Now, that allows me to loop through the favorites (on a user's "favorites" page, for example) and get the associated blog objects via {{ favorite.content_object.title }}.

What I want now, and can't figure out, is what I need to do to the blog model to allow me to have some tether to the favorite (so when it is displayed in a list it can be highlighted, for example).

Here is the blog model:

### blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from category.models import Category
from section.models import Section
from favorite.models import Favorite
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Blog(models.Model):
        title           = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=140, editable=False)
        author          = models.ForeignKey(User)
        homepage        = models.URLField()
        feed            = models.URLField()
        description     = models.TextField()
        page_views      = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0 )
        created_on      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
        updated_on      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.title

        @models.permalink
        def get_absolute_url(self):
                return ('blog.views.show', [str(self.slug)])

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if not self.slug:
                        slug = slugify(self.title)
                        duplicate_count = Blog.objects.filter(slug__startswith = slug).count()
                        if duplicate_count:
                                slug = slug + str(duplicate_count)
                        self.slug = slug
                super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Entry(models.Model):
        blog            = models.ForeignKey('Blog')
        title           = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=140, editable=False)
        description     = models.TextField()
        url             = models.URLField(unique=True)
        image           = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
        created_on      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.title

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if not self.slug:
                        slug = slugify(self.title)
                        duplicate_count = Entry.objects.filter(slug__startswith = slug).count()
                        if duplicate_count:
                                slug = slug + str(duplicate_count)
                        self.slug = slug
                super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Entry"
                verbose_name_plural = "Entries"
```

Any guidance?

Comment: Not what you are asking, but there are a number of `AutoSlugField` s out there which would eliminate the need for all that save code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django doc on it is here:  [Reverse generic relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations).  Basically on the Blog model itself you can add a `GenericRelation`...

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    favorites = generic.GenericRelation(Favorite)
```

For a given blog you can find all of the `Favorite` models that are associated with it...

```
b = Blog.objects.get(slug='hello-world-blog-slug')
all_blog_favorites = b.favorites.objects.all()
```

Or see if the current user has the blog favorited...

```
user_has_blog_favorited = b.favorites.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists()
```

Comment: The first bit completely stopped the errors I was having.  Apparently I had mixed up which parts went where, as well as typoed 'generic.GenericRelation' as 'models.GenericRelation'.  Call me dumb, but I can't figure out where to put the second and third code blocks you provided.

Comment: The other code blocks are showing how the generic relations API is used, most likely in the view (or if it's a common query, a method on the blog itself)